# Symfony 6.2 Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, symfony6

I am running into a situation where I am creating an application in symfony 6.2 to replace a legacy application.  We are keeping all the users and I have a migration command that is moving the users from the legacy application to the new one.  The problem I am running into has to do with the users’ passwords.

My preferred workflow would be:

- User logs into new application
- Form based authentication tests the credentials
- Attempt to login to the legacy application API on credential test failure
- Encode and store password in new application when the API login to the legacy application succeeds

I am stuck at the point of determining that the current user's credentials do not work on the new application and performing the API call to encode the password and store it.

Preferably I would like to be able to chain authenticators though I do not see that as an option.

I have created a custom authenticator that would perform the actions needed against the legacy API and on success encode and store the provided password to the user object.

I am wondering whether my custom authenticator has to handle the new application login form and security tasks?

Thanks in advance :)